# HERE - Error 403 with regionDefinition type circle

Tags: matrix, here-api, http-status-code-403, here-routing

I'm migrating from version 7 to version 8 to submit a matrix for calculation.

I receive this error when I post to https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?apiKey=MY_API_KEY&async=false :

```
{
    "title": "insufficient permissions",
    "status": 403,
    "code": "E601110",
    "cause": "forbidden: your current plan is limited to requests of size up to 15 origins and 100 destinations (max. 15x100), or 100 origins and 1 destination (max. 100x1)",
    "action": "Please contact support for more information.",
    "correlationId": "f50569c8-ee29-49bf-b5c8-08847eebab69"
}
```

To be sure about my test, I copied the example in https://developer.here.com/documentation/matrix-routing-api/8.4.0/api-reference-swagger.html named "Region mode (circle with traffic departure time) and I cloned many times an origin :

```
{
    "origins": [
        {
            "lat": 52.5309,
            "lng": 13.3849
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5202,
            "lng": 13.373
        }
    ],
    "destinations": [
        {
            "lat": 52.522,
            "lng": 13.4133
        },
        {
            "lat": 52.5163,
            "lng": 13.3777
        }
    ],
    "departureTime": "2020-10-19T08:00:00-01:00",
    "regionDefinition": {
        "type": "circle",
        "center": {
            "lat": 52.5309,
            "lng": 13.3849
        },
        "radius": 25000
    }
}
```

Same error

Comment: Hi, sry for the inconvenient. Could you please let us know what your plan is? Is it a freemium account or anything else? Thanks

Comment: Not a freemium account. Professional one. Apparently, someone contacted you about this problem.

Comment: Hey Frédérick, sry about the delay. We don't have any restrictions for users to migrate from V7 to V8. In your case, we would need more info from you. Could you please use this link and select "I have a developer-related or tech question" from the drop down list and fill out the info. https://developer.here.com/?form_id=2227&form_category=contact-us&cta_id=521_contact-us&detailed_source=cms.developer.here.com%2F (It asks some info which won't be a good idea to post here)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize: Here don't have any restrictions for users to migrate from V7 to V8. In your case, we would need more info from you. Could you please use this link and select "I have a developer-related or tech question" from the drop down list and fill out the info.
https://developer.here.com/help